# How can I increase the value of somaxconn?

Tags: linux-networking

I can check its value by `cat /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn`,

is it OK if I change it simply by `echo 1024 > /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn`?

Answer (score 83):

Yes. Alternatively, you can use:

```
sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=1024
```

Add `net.core.somaxconn=1024` to /etc/sysctl.conf for it to become permanent (be reapplied after booting).

Comment: so both `/proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn` and `/etc/sysctl.conf` are persistent?

Comment: @linux_user - no, only modifying `/etc/sysctl.conf` is persistent. `/proc` is not a "real" filesystem, only a filesystem interface to the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

yes `/proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn` is writable if you have the permissions to do so.

Comment: You would have to modify /etc/sysctl.conf as root to make it persistent. /proc is not a real file system